# DatabaseMigrations Not Found In Laravel 5.0

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I was watching a video of Unit Testing of **Laravel 5.4**, and the tutor uses

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
```

and

```
use DatabaseMigrations;
```

inside the testing file

In **Laravel 5.0**, there are no such files and I cannot use DatabaseMigrations in my testing file.

I get error like

> Fatal error: Trait 'Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations'
>   not found

Are there any replacements in **Laravel 5.0**

Answer (score 1):

Just these in command prompt "php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users" this will create create_users_table migration.
after that run this command "php artisan migrate" this will create users table in a database. Thanks

Comment: Yes. I agree with you. I was searching for the alternative that can be used in Laravel 5.0